# Correct procedure on dupehammered questions if the tags change and question improved?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, dupehammer

My question: Was it inappropriate to flag for mod?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173089/css-is-not-applying-on-the-ajax-response

1. I hammer closed as duplicate
2. User updated question and tags and asked to reopen the now improved question.
3. I clicked reopen but was only allowed to vote due to the changed tags
4. To expedite the reopen, I flagged for moderator to reopen
5. Nothing happened so I suggested user to delete and write another question with the now improved text. He complied.

I am now reviewing and am told my flag was declined.

Comment: Most likely it was declined because reopening a question can be handled by the community and needs not mod interaction.  As a side note if you need help reopening a question you can stop in the [SOCVR chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask users there for help.

Comment: If the OP deleted their question before a moderator got to your flag, it is possible the moderator saw your comments on the Q, saw the Q was deleted, and figured the OP did what you suggested so the whole thing was moot. This would be similar to how you can flag an answer NAA, it gets comments in review, the author comes back to fix it, and eventually a moderator declines the flag because the answer is fine by the time a moderator sees the flag.

Comment: So I should not worry too much when being declined?

Comment: @mplungjan I would not worry about one declined flag. The scenario I gave with NAA answers has happened to me a few times. Everybody gets declined flags every now and then.

Comment: Thanks. So I can delete this question or leave it?

Comment: Leave it I'd say. Someone should make an answer out of the comments though.

Comment: Now I left it. Now it is being voted down. Great.

Comment: @NathanOliver please answer so I can close this

Comment: @mplungjan Votes on Meta don't count against your rep like the main site. Downvotes are routine on Meta

Comment: I know. I still don't like then :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it was declined because reopening a question can be handled by the community and does not need any moderator intervention.  Mod flags are intended for things that the community cannot handle.

As a side note if you need help reopening a question you can stop in the [SOCVR chat room](http://socvr.org/) and ask users there for help.

As Servy noted telling a user to just delete and repost the same question is frowned upon as it circumvents the system.  There are times when that really is the only alternative if a question gets really derailed but normally you should wait for the process to handle itself.  When you vote to reopen it places the question in the reopen review queue.  From there other users will see it and vote as they see fit.  One thing you can do to help is to edit the question and explain why it is not a dupe.  This will help reviewers that come across it.

Answer (score 4):

You should not flag a moderator for issues that the community won't have any problem solving, such as reopening a closed question.  Mods are there to handle issues that the community isn't able to resolve.

It's not appropriate to go around telling people to delete and re-create their questions when they've been closed in order to get them reopened.  This is an abuse of the system.

Comment: You misunderstood. **I** hammerclosed the question based on the main question. The user removed the duplicate part and elaborated on the other part and removed the JS tag, leaving the CSS issue. Since it was closed and my reopen did not open it, I tried to get it reopened but nothing happened, I then flagged it. Nothing happened. I then suggested the user to delete the now improved and valid question and reopen it as a fresh question.

Comment: @mplungjan No, I'm not misunderstanding anything at all.  The fact that, due to an edit, you no longer have a unilateral reopen vote doesn't merit moderator attention.  Cast your reopen vote and then move on, and let other people cast their reopen votes if they feel that it's merited.  Again, the fact that you think the question merits reopening doesn't mean that it's appropriate to delete and re-ask a closed question to subvert the closure system and get it reopened.

Comment: Come on. Subvert is nowhere near the intent here.

Comment: @mplungjan It's *exactly* the intent here.  Your explicit purpose here is to avoid having to reopen the question, and instead subvert the reopen process by posting a new question.  If you weren't trying to subvert the closure system you'd just wait for the question to be reopened.  Deleting and recreating the question just to avoid needing to get the reopen votes needed is the *definition* of subverting the system.

Comment: The intent was to remove a now wrongly labelled and down voted question from the path it was on. Never mind - won't happen again. Feel free to delete your answer so I can delete my question

Comment: @mplungjan If the intent was to remove the question then you wouldn't be suggesting it be re-posted.  The act of re-posting it means that the explicit purpose was to subvert the closure process, and apparently the voting process, by removing downvotes on the post.  That's not okay.

Comment: The downvotes would of course exclusively have been due to the duplication if any. I would not try to convince someone to re-ask the same question. The amended issue had very little in common with the original

Comment: @mplungjan Telling someone to delete and then re-post the exact same question isn't telling them to re-ask the same question?  Really?  You're sticking with that?  The question was literally copy-pasted from the deleted question to the new question.  It was not a completely different question.

Comment: Please see the edit history.

Comment: @mplungjan I did look at the edit history.  The new question was a character for character duplicate of the deleted question.  It was re-posted for the explicit purpose of removing the closure, not because it was a new question.

Comment: What is your beef with me? 1. The question was not voted down by the way. 2. The question was ORIGINALLY about applying DATATABLE after Ajax load. That was correctly hammerclosed as duplicate by ME. The NEW IMPROVED question was about applying CSS on the fourth cell:  _@mplungjan This is not just about datatables. I have css not applying on ajax response. I have gone through the threads already and those dint served the purpose. please remove the duplicate tag_

Comment: @mplungjan I don't have any beef with you.  I'm answering the question that you asked.  You apparently have a beef with me, and simply don't like being told that what you did was wrong, when you did something wrong.  The fact that you have no problem with someone else posting an answer telling you basically the same thing would imply that you do indeed have some problem with me.  *You* said that you suggested re-posting it because of votes on it, so saying that you said that is true regardless of the actual votes on the post.

Comment: If the question was inappropriate edited to change what it was asking, then you should have told the author not to completely change the question that they were asking and to ask a new question, rather than editing a new question into an existing question, and if you wanted to be told how to deal with that situation on meta, you'd need to actually mention that the question was radically edited into a new question, rather than what you did ask, which said that the question was simply erroneously closed.

Comment: _User updated question and tags and asked to reopen the now improved question._

Comment: I of course completely agree not to try and circumvent anything. I just felt sorry for the guy in this case since it was my initial hammerclose that stopped him from getting an answer quickly

Comment: @mplungjan The fact that you feel sorry for someone doesn't make it okay to suggest that they circumvent the system, nor does it mean that you weren't telling them to circumvent the system, because that's *exactly* what you were doing.

Comment: No I was not. I suggested to ask the separate CSS question and delete the first DATATABLE one since it was no longer clear why it was flagged or not. So no.

Comment: Saying that they should copy-paste their question into a new question and re-ask it because it is closed (when you don't think it should be) is performing an action for the sole purpose of not needing to actually reopen a question that you think needs to be reopened.  That's subverting that system.  Just saying that it's not *when you were doing something for the explicit purpose of not needing to use that system* is meaningless, because that's what it means to subvert a system.